# What is the easiest way to validate a set of parameters for a method call via reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am wondering what is the easiest (or native) way of validating parameters types of an object array having the MethodInfo to invoke and the object[].

Example:

Let's say i have a method Foo which receives a parameter of type int.
Via reflection i obtained the method's MethodInfo, from where i can call invoke passing an object array.

If i call invoke passing a array of object with a single int, it's gonna be ok.
If i call invoke passing a array of object with 2 strings on it, it's not gonna be ok.

How can i be sure that the objects passed on invoke are compatible with the methods parameters types.

Comment: What is there to validate about it?

Comment: If you're using `Invoke`, you would have to pass in the parameters as an `object` array. You should be able to do your validation with that, no?

Comment: I have no idea what "type validation" is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the general case this could be quite complicated -- in essence you would be implementing part of the compiler. Fortunately [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) knows a whole lot about type conversions, so a reasonable first attempt would be

```
var compatible = methodInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType)
                     .Zip(objArray, Tuple.Create)
                     .All(t => t.Item1.IsAssignableFrom(t.Item2.GetType()));
```

This gets the types of the formal arguments out of the `MethodInfo`, pairs them up with the actual object at hand and confirms that each object can be assigned to a variable of the corresponding type.

Comment: simple and straight to the point.